# How do I get back Grub Bootloader back if it has suddenly disappeared?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I was using Ubuntu 17.04 and had to install some packages but I was encountering some errors(like Error 404) and I wasn't also able to update apt-get so I followed this online tutorial and made some changes in the sources.list after which I was able to update apt-get and install the packages. However on restarting my PC now  it directly goes to Windows 10 without showing the bootloader like it used to do

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. 17.04 was released 2017-April (hence 17.04) with 9 months of support life. It reached its EOL in Jan-2018 and is now off-topic on this site. Use an LTS (long-term-support) release if the 9 month window is too short for you.

Comment: Possible off-topic question. 17.04 is EOL, and only how-to-upgrade questions are now on-topic.  The OP doesn't appear to be asking for the following, but .. https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release  or https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I can't see how an update could cause this, however I'd suggest booting live media & looking for issues, then re-installing the MBR (*assuming you were using grub to select which you want to run*).  I'd also suggest backing up your data, and moving to a supported release (*17.04 upgrades to 17.10, where 17.10 will be EOL in just over a month, so upgrade before that door closes*); or use this issue as a chance to clean-install 18.04 LTS after you've backed up of course.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get back into Linux ?

Is Windows located on a separated hard-disk ?

You could re-install with 18.04 LTS in expert-modus - but only re-install the root-files in the root-partition of '/' - and do not format the previous /home - Partition of your linux and also do not format the windows-Partition. This way grub will be reinstalled too (into MBR of sda? - or into MBR of root-harddisk) and update-grub2 will be done automatically.

This way Windows will be accepted and your previous Linux-/home partition will be taken over.